# Make all to all relationship among the element present in list in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

https://community.neo4j.com/t/make-all-to-all-relationship-among-the-element-present-in-list/37390
here is the link of same question

I have csv file with two column as source and target.
I need to make all to all relationship between all the element in the target column of each respective source.

here is my query, I am not able to make all to all relationship.

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS row

unwind (split(row.target,'|'))  as target

merge (n:MyNode{name:row.source})
merge (m:MyNode{name:target})
merge (m) -[:TO{weight:row.weight}]->(n)

merge (m) -[:r]-(m)  // not sure about this line
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Eager operations in the plan will complicate this, making you unable to use USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV (which you would need for processing any large CSV).

(more info on [Eager behavior here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/cypher-sleuthing-the-eager-operator/10730))

In Neo4j 4.1 or 4.2 you could use subqueries to get around this, but that will not hold for 4.3 and above.

With subqueries:

```
LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS row
MERGE (n:MyNode{name:row.source})
WITH row, n
CALL {
    WITH row, n
    UNWIND (split(row.target,'|'))  as target
    MERGE (m:MyNode{name:target})
    MERGE (m) -[:TO{weight:row.weight}]->(n)
    
    WITH collect(m) as targets
    UNWIND targets as t1
    UNWIND targets as t2

    WITH t1, t2
    WHERE id(t1) < id(t2)
    MERGE (t1)-[:r]-(t2)  
    
    RETURN true as result
}

RETURN result
```

For versions 4.0 and below, subqueries are not available, and with versions 4.3.x (not yet released) and above, subqueries no longer workaround Eager operators, so this won't work.

Instead, you could use `apoc.cypher.doIt()` in place of the subquery, which will work around the Eager (but you'll have to work with Cypher query string), or instead you can do 3 passes through your CSV:

First pass to MERGE the source node

Second pass to only split() and MERGE the target nodes.

Third pass to MATCH to both source and targets and MERGE the relationships between them.

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve that after the import, rather than during by doing something like this

```
match (s:Source)-[:TO]-(t:Target)
with s, collect (t) as targets
unwind targets as target
foreach (n in targets | merge (n)-[:r]-(target))
```

Comment: Be aware that will also add loops, relationships from each target to itself.

Comment: Also it may be more performant if you MATCHed to s:Source and used a pattern comprehension to get targets, avoiding the collect() aggregation (since a collect() over a high number of :Source nodes could cause problems for the heap)

Answer (score 0):

```
    LOAD CSV with headers FROM 'file:///sample.csv' AS row
MERGE (n:MyNode:domain{name:row.source})
WITH row, n
CALL {
    WITH row, n
    UNWIND (split(row.target,'|'))  as target
    MERGE (m:MyNode:token{name:target})
    MERGE (m) -[:TO{weight:row.weight}]->(n)
    
    WITH collect(m) as targets
    UNWIND targets as t1
    UNWIND targets as t2

    WITH t1, t2
    WHERE id(t1) < id(t2)
    MERGE (t1)-[:token_join]-(t2)  
    
    RETURN true as result
}

WITH n
CALL{
WITH n
match (d1:domain)
match (d2:domain)

WITH d1,d2
WHERE id(d1) < id(d2)
MERGE (d1)-[:domain_join]-(d2)  
return true as result
}

match (nodes) return nodes
```

did little modification in above code....